Does it matter who I dispatch for gathering?
When dispatching a gatherer to an area for resources on the map, I can choose to send Tauemon, Myrthe, Kinta, Yui, or Kaimaru. Does it matter which person I dispatch for gathering? Does the person I choose affect the resources I get back?


According to the wiki,

Take note that different people will focus more on certain things as they gather; Kaimaru leans more towards fertilizer, Myrthe leans more towards ingredients, Kinta leans towards ores and materials, Yui focuses more on gathering fruit and plants, and Tauemon has no real focus, opting to gather a balanced mix of items. It is recommended that at the start of each day, you send people gathering (given that you have no other business with them).


Take that Malady!

...am I missing something?

@pinckerman What would make you think that?

Why did you mention Malady in the first place? lol

@pinckerman A little while ago, Malady answered this question. You can read more about what's going under comments of Malady's answer, but essentially what's going is I've answered all of Stevoisiak's questions about this game so far, but then Malady broke the "streak". I'm joking that I got to answer first.

Lol I totally understand, I'm usually the one that answers Stevoisiak's questions :D
